# Categorize item according to their types

Tags: sql

I have an inventory table in database that shows id, code, description and class1. It looks a bit like this:

```
  id code  description          class1
 --------------------------------------
  1  001   Office stationary     101   
  2  002   Computer stationary   101                    
  3  003   Documents             101                                    
  4  001   Surgical products     107                            
  5  002   Urological products   107
```

How do I categorize them according to class1? What condition should I use?

I wanted the output to look more like this:

**101**
- 001 Office stationary
- 002 Computer stationary
- 003 Documents

**107**
- 001 Surgical products
- 002 Urological products

Comment: Tag which flavor of RDBMS you are using

Comment: SQL query returns data in tabular format. (rows and columns), what you are asking for is getting a formatted the output from the query that is not in rows/columns. My suggestion would be to let the application layer handle this

Answer (score 0):

I’m fairly novice at sql but you would want to do a s SELECT x WHERE class1 = 101 repeat the query but for 107 if you want to omit a row you will need to do another command either MID LEFT OR RIGHT. If you want assorted by numerical order you could do that too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ms sql solution

```
WITH DATA (id,code,description,class1) as(
select  1,  '001',   'Office stationary',     101   union all
select  2,  '002',   'Computer stationary',   101   union all                 
select  3,  '003',   'Documents',             101   union all                        
select  4,  '001',   'Surgical products',     107   union all       
select  5,  '002',   'Urological products',   107
)
select concat(d.class1,' - ',STRING_AGG(concat(d.code,' ',d.description),' - ')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY d.code)) a
from DATA d
group by d.class1
```

[image]